# Compile all Flows?

Tags: visual-workflow, compile-error, compile, subflow, dependency-api

Is there a simple mechanism to "**compile all Flows**" (e.g. in the way there is for Apex classes and triggers)?

If not, what's the next fastest way to verify that dependencies aren't broken when I change the names of public variables on sub-Flows, e.g.?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any mechanism.

I believe the fastest way would be dealing with the metadata. You can do this in a couple different ways

1. Pull your flow metadata in VS Code to search against the variable name to see if it's referenced anywhere.

   - `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow`
   - Ctrl + Shift + F - type in the variable name in the search
   - Can filter by files to include, exclude, etc.
2. Pull all flows and immediately try deploying them into the same environment to get that feedback of any issues.

   - `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow`
   - `sfdx force:source:deploy -m Flow`

Comment: not sure #2 would work if you had apex or quick actions interacting with flow inputs or output variables. The binding is by variableName (case sensitive); would work for sub-flows though

Comment: true - apex you could use the compilation button available for it but quick actions (and others) would probably best be covered by searching manually vs. adding more to your retrieve/deploy to cover dependencies.